# How to pass a parameter value to a ColdFusion database query

Tags: coldfusion

I have written a database query to extract information in ColdFusion and I want to know how may I pass a value to the WHERE clause to get the relevant data. This is my code sample. can any one help?

```
<cfquery name="FILM_STRIP_QUERY" datasource="#dsn#">
select   distinct tm.id as teachingmoduleid,
        (select concat(prs.first_name, ' ',prs.last_name) AS Video_presenter from presentations pss
            inner join topics tpcs on tpcs.id = pss.topic_id
            inner join presenters prs on prs.id = pss.presenter_id
            where pss.name = ps.name
            and tpcs.title = tp.title
            ) AS video_presenter,
        (select pss.43_png from presentations pss
            inner join topics tpcs on tpcs.id = pss.topic_id
            inner join presenters prs on prs.id = pss.presenter_id
            where pss.name = ps.name
            and tpcs.title = tp.title) AS png_name
        from teaching_modules  tm 
        inner join tm_segments sg on sg.module_id =  tm.id
        inner join topics tp on tp.id =  sg.topic_id
        inner join presenters prs on prs.id = tm.presenter_id
        left outer  join presentations ps on ps.id = sg.presentation_id
        where tm.id = 
</cfquery>
```

and this is the calling function

```
<cfloop = "FILM_STRIP_QUERY">
    <!--- this is where I wanna pass the parameter--->
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a CFC, then a function like this would work, including  the query name ensuring CF releases the memory from the local variable declaration. Also uses the  parameter and the cfqueryparam function.

```
<cffunction name="getFILM_STRIP" access="public" returntype="query" output="false">
     <cfargument name="id" required="Yes" type="numeric">

     <cfset FILM_STRIP_QUERY = "">

     <cfquery name="FILM_STRIP_QUERY" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
         <!--- select statement --->
         WHERE colname = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value=#arguments.id# />
     </cfquery>

     <cfreturn FILM_STRIP_QUERY>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: don't forget to VAR scope FILM_STRIP_QUERY.  Also this code won't work as-is, should be <cfreturn FILM_STRIP_QUERY>

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<cfset tmId = 5 />
<!--- or something like <cfset tmId = url.id /> --->
<cfquery name="FILM_STRIP_QUERY" datasource="#dsn#">
  <!--- SELECT cols FROM wherever etc... --->
  WHERE tm.id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#tmId#" />
</cfquery>
```

You could just do #tmid# without the CFQueryParam tag, but it's a good idea to use it for added security (validation) and the database will also cache the execution plan, hopefully improving performance the next time the query executes.

Comment: how to set the "tmid" from the calling function?

Comment: you need to pass in the tmid to the function. in your `<cfinvoke>` tag add `tmid="#form.tmid#"` You can use any variable name inside your cfinvoke function. Check out Adobe's live docs for more information http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e0a.html

Comment: Depends on how you're calling the function.  If you're doing filmQuery(5) then it'll be arguments[1], unless you've added a CFArgument tag into your function.  Try looking up information about CFFunction, CFComponent (if you're using it) and CFArgument.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the cfqueryparam tag to do this. This helps DB execution and also helps prevent SQL injection. e.g.

```
where tm.id = <cfqueryparam value="#form.ID#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
```